# How to target iOS 5 and iOS 6

Tags: ios5, ios6, iphone-5

Here's my predicament. I have an app that I would like to update to handle the new screen size (among other things) of the iPhone 5. In order to do this I need to target iOS 6. But by targetting iOS 6 I'm preventing a large number of iPhone users from downloading my app since it will take quite some time for people to get around to upgrading to iOS 6 on their iPhone 4/4S. So what is the best approach? How do I move ahead, but at the same time provide backwards compatibility? Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your app supports the new 4" iPhone 5 screen size, there is no need to exclude support for previous iOS versions.

All you need to do is create a 4" sized launch image, and iOS 6 will recognise that and launch your app with the full screen size. Older versions of iOS will ignore the strange size launch image, and continue to work as they always have.

You do need to upgrade to Xcode 4.5 to add this image, but you can leave the "Deployment Target" for your project at 5.0 or 4.3 or whatever.

Comment: Do xib-based projects use distinct xib files for the larger iPhone 5 screen? (e.g. for regular and retina images, filenames are image.png and image@2x.png)

Comment: @bneely: I haven't needed to create distinct xib files, as long as your layout constraints can deal with the different screen dimensions.